# How to remove the nth hexadecimal digit of a integer number without using Strings?

Tags: java, integer, hex, bit-manipulation

Consider a hexadecimal integer value such as `n = 0x12345`, how to get `0x1235` as result by doing `remove(n, 3)` (big endian)?

For the inputs above I think this can be achieved by performing some bitwising steps:

- `partA` = extract the part from index `0` to `targetIndex - 1` (should return `0x123`);
- `partB` = extract the part from `targetIndex + 1` to `length(value) - 1` (`0x5`);
- result, then, can be expressed by `((partA << length(partB) | partB)`, giving the `0x1235` result.

However I'm still confused in how to implement it, once each hex digit occupies 4 spaces. Also, I don't know a good way to retrieve the length of the numbers.

This can be easily done with strings however I need to use this in a context of thousands of iterations and don't think Strings is a good idea to choose.

So, what is a good way to this removing without Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the idea you describe, this can be done by creating a mask for both the upper and the lower part, shifting the upper part, and then reassembling.

```
int remove(int x, int i) {
    // create a mask covering the highest 1-bit and all lower bits
    int m = x;
    m |= (m >>> 1);
    m |= (m >>> 2);
    m |= (m >>> 4);
    m |= (m >>> 8);
    m |= (m >>> 16);
    // clamp to 4-bit boundary
    int l = m & 0x11111110;
    m = l - (l >>> 4);
    // shift to select relevant position
    m >>>= 4 * i;
    // assemble result
    return ((x & ~(m << 4)) >>> 4) | (x & m);
}
```

where ">>>" is an unsigned shift.

As a note, if 0 indicates the highest hex digit in a 32-bit word independent of the input, this is much simpler:

```
int remove(int x, int i) {
    int m = 0xffffffff >>> (4*i);
    return ((x & ~m) >>> 4) | (x & (m >>> 4));
}
```

Comment: I like the idea and wrote one of my own which is different.  But unfortunately, from my tests at least, this doesn't seem to work  Thought you would want to know so you can test it yourself and make any changes.

Comment: Could you please tell me for which input you're getting a wrong result?

Comment: Try these.  According to the OP, 0 should be the first on the left, 1,the second and so on.  System.out.printf("%X%n",remove(0xABCDEF, 0));
  System.out.printf("%X%n",remove(0xABCDEF, 1));
  System.out.printf("%X%n",remove(0xABCDEF, 2));
  System.out.printf("%X%n",remove(0xABCDEF, 3));

Comment: OK, I was assuming that numbering starts with 0 as the highest 4-bit group (the question mentions "big-endian" which is exactly that). It seems you're assuming something different although I'm not sure what.

Comment: I just went by the first sentence and the example with the method call. I ignored the "big-endian" statement. Specifying 3 removed the 4 from the number so I presumed the OP was counting from the left starting with 0.

Comment: Very smart! However, by calling `remove(0x12345, 2)` it returns `12345` instead of `1245`. Also, `remove(0x112334, 0)` returns `12334` and so on. Even ignoring endian ordering it seems not work. Can you fix?

Comment: With second argument "2", it removes the third-from-top of 8 hex digits (e.g. remove(0x12345678, 2) yields 0x1245678). I'm still not sure what it is you actually want. What is remove(0x112334, 0) supposed to yield?

Comment: *With second argument "2", it removes the third-from-top of 8 hex digits (e.g. remove(0x12345678, 2).*  That's correct.  But try it with 0x1234567 and then 0x123456, and so on.  It should always remove the `3`

Comment: I see, I've added a version for this. Unfortunately it's much more involved, since already finding the topmost set bit is not easy.

Comment: Correct results and incredible performance! I just tried to call `remove(0x112334, 0)` `Integer.MAX_VALUE` times and took just 7 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

Replace operations using 10 with operations using 16.

## Demo

**Using Bitwise Operator:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0x12345;
        int temp = n;
        int length = 0;

        // Find length
        while (temp != 0) {
            length++;
            temp /= 16;
        }
        System.out.println("Length of the number: " + length);

        // Remove digit at index 3
        int m = n;
        int index = 3;
        for (int i = index + 1; i <= length; i++) {
            m /= 16;
        }
        m *= 1 << ((length - index - 1) << 2);
        m += n % (1 << ((length - index - 1) << 2));
        System.out.println("The number after removing digit at index " + index + ": 0x" + Integer.toHexString(m));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Length of the number: 5
The number after removing digit at index 3: 0x1235
```

**Using `Math::pow`:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 0x12345;
        int temp = n;
        int length = 0;

        // Find length
        while (temp != 0) {
            length++;
            temp /= 16;
        }
        System.out.println("Length of the number: " + length);

        // Remove digit at index 3
        int m = n;
        int index = 3;
        for (int i = index + 1; i <= length; i++) {
            m /= 16;
        }
        m *= ((int) (Math.pow(16, length - index - 1)));
        m += n % ((int) (Math.pow(16, length - index - 1)));
        System.out.println("The number after removing digit at index " + index + ": 0x" + Integer.toHexString(m));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Length of the number: 5
The number after removing digit at index 3: 0x1235
```

---

**JavaScript version:**

```
n = parseInt(12345, 16);
temp = n;
length = 0;

// Find length
while (temp != 0) {
    length++;
    temp = Math.floor(temp / 16);
}
console.log("Length of the number: " + length);

// Remove digit at index 3
m = n;
index = 3;
for (i = index + 1; i <= length; i++) {
    m = Math.floor(m / 16);
}
m *= 1 << ((length - index - 1) << 2);
m += n % (1 << ((length - index - 1) << 2));
console.log("The number after removing digit at index " + index + ": 0x" + m.toString(16));
```

Comment: Doing this with `n = 0x12345` and `index = 2` gives `165` instead of `1245` and with `n = 0x11233455` and `index = 4` gives `11685` instead of `1123455`. Works only for  `n = 0x12345` and `index = 3`?

Comment: @LucasSousa - I've corrected the problem. Feel free to comment in case of any further issue.

Comment: Very amazing! Wroked well in all my tests. Thank you.

Comment: Can someone provide a Javascript version from this answer?

Comment: I'm not good at Javascript but I'll try and post the Javascript version.

Comment: @LucasSousa - I've posted the JavaScript version. Since JavaScript is not my area of expertise, I struggled a bit but finally, I was able to make it.

Comment: Thank you @Arvind. I was afraid with the castings but it is working well.

Comment: Great! Wish you success!

Answer (score 1):

This works by writing a method to remove from the right but adjusting the parameter to remove from the left.  The bonus is that a remove from the right is also available for use. This method uses `longs` to maximize the length of the hex value.

```
long n = 0x12DFABCA12L;
int r = 3;
System.out.println("Supplied value: " + Long.toHexString(n).toUpperCase());
n = removeNthFromTheRight(n, r);
System.out.printf("Counting %d from the right: %X%n", r, n);
n = 0x12DFABCA12L;
n = removeNthFromTheLeft(n, r);
System.out.printf("Counting %d from the left:  %X%n", r, n);
```

Prints

```
Supplied value: 12DFABCA12
Counting 3 from the right: 12DFABA12
Counting 3 from the left:  12DABCA12
```

This works by recursively removing a digit from the end until just before the one you want to remove.   Then remove that and return thru the call stack, rebuilding the number with the original values.

This method counts from the right.

```
public static long removeNthFromTheRight(long v, int n) {
    if (v <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough digits");
    }
    // save hex digit
    long k = v % 16;
    while (n > 0) {
    // continue removing digit until one
    // before the one you want to remove
    return removeNthFromTheRight(v / 16, n - 1) * 16 + k;
}
if (n == 0) {
    // and ignore that digit.
    v /= 16;
}
return v;
}
```

This method counts from the left. It simply adjusts the value of `n` and then calls `removeFromTheRight`.

```
public static long removeNthFromTheLeft(long v, int n) {
    ndigits = (67-Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(v))>>2;

    // Now just call removeNthFromTheRight with modified paramaters.
    return removeNthFromTheRight(v, ndigits - n - 1);
}
```

Here is my version using bit manipulation with explanation.

- the highest set bit helps find the offset for the mask. For a `long` that bit is 64-the number of leading zeroes. To get the number of hex digits, one must divide by 4.  To account for numbers evenly divisible by 4, it is necessary to add 3 before dividing.  So that makes the number of digits:

  `digits = (67-Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(i))>>2`;
  which then requires it to be adjusted to mask the appropriate parts of the number.

  `offset = digits-i - 1`
- `m` is the mask to mask off the digit to be removed. So start with a `-1L (all hex 'F')` and right shift `4*(16-offset)` bits. This will result in a mask that masks everything to the right of the digit to be removed.
  Note: If `offset` is `0` the shift operator will be `64` and no bits will be shifted.  To accommodate this, the shift operation is broken up into two operations.
- Now simply mask off the low order bits
  `v & m`
- And the high order bits right shifted `4` bits to eliminate the desired digit.
  `(v>>>4)^ ~m`
- and then the two parts are simply OR'd together.

```
    static long remove(long v, int i) {
        int offset = ((67 - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(v))>>2) - i - 1;
        long m = (-1L >>> (4*(16 - offset) - 1)) >> 1;
        return ((v >>> 4) & ~m) | (v & m);
    }
```

Comment: Can I assume that left/right is the endian ordering?

Comment: I guess. It just describes from which side the value is counted from.

Comment: Lucas, I wrote a bit shifting version which works just fine.  But I don't want to steal Falk's thunder so I'm giving him time to fix it.

Comment: Lucas,  I added my version using bit shifting and was hoping you could check it out.  It may be a tad slower since it works with longs to allow wider arguments.

Comment: Pretty solution and a great explanation as well! Thank you. :)